# How to make Text View transparent?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, textview

How can I make a Text View's background transparent in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click on the Text view and for background color, choose "clear color".

Answer (score 4):

in IB:
change background color and use opacity to make it transparent.

in code:

```
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color of a UIKit text view(UITextView) programmatically in Swift, you can use the **clear** property on the UIColor object:

```
textView.backgroundColor = .clear
```